# UIWebView in modalviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am displaying a UIWebview in a view controller that is presented as a modal view controller of style "form sheet". In that web view I am presenting a PDF file.
Here's what it looks like:

[image]

My problem is that it won't fit (width wise) despite me calling setScaledPageToFit. Also, I can't pan the web view width wise so I can't even see what is cut off. I have called these methods of the web view:

```
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: How did you add the `UIWebView` to the view? Did you set the frame and autoresizing masks?

Comment: Ah, yes, just figured it out. I set the autoresizing masks to flexible width. Do you want to leave it as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the frame and autoresizing masks of the `UIWebView`

Anchor it to all sides of the superview and set the flexible width and height. Make sure the frame covers the bounds of the superview.